# tabs not coming on iphone screen

Tags: iphone

i have written an iphone application but when i run it only blank screen comes and nothing else is displayed.

Comment: what's your application base?

Comment: Did you add your tab to window?

Comment: write some code so we try to find solution dear..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the window type view connect the labels, buttons and textfiels with the window file in the xib file of the program .then go to file in the interface builder and press simulate interference.icons and buttons will appear on the  simulator